# How to remove files older than in a huge directory

Tags: files, directory

I have a directory with over 13 milion files and I want to remove some of them based on mtime, how do I do it efficiently? It's on ext4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably won't get more efficient than:

```
find /dir -type f -mtime +6 -delete
```

To delete files older than 7 (yes, 7, not 6) days.

In any case, you'll need to do one `lstat()` system call on each file to determine its last modification time. Deleting a file (`unlink()`ing it from a directory) is expensive as it needs to edit the contents of the directory, update the directory's modification time, update the file's link count in the inode and update block/extent allocation information.

Using `-delete` (a GNU extension) is efficient as then the `unlink()` is done by `find` directly without having to invoke a separate `rm` utility. It implies `-depth`, but I don't expect that would make much difference in terms of performance.